# Relationship between the Hausdorff dimension and the Box-counting dimension

Tags: analysis, geometry, fractals, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

In [*Fractal Geometry* by Falconer](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/0470013850) the author writes:

> If $1<\mathcal H^s(F)=\lim_{\delta\to0}\mathcal H_\delta^s(F)$
>   then $\log N_\delta(F)+s\log\delta>0$ if $\delta$ is sufficiently small.
>   Thus $s\leqslant\underline{\lim}_{\delta\to0}\log N_\delta(F)/-\log\delta$ so
>   $$\dim_HF\leqslant\underline\dim_BF\leqslant\overline\dim_BF\tag{3.17}$$
>   for every $F\subset\mathbb R^n$.
>   We do *not* in general get equality here.
>   Although Hausdorff and box dimensions are equal for many ‘reasonably regular’
>   sets, there are plenty of examples where this inequality is strict.

What happens in the case $\mathcal{H}^s(F) \leq 1$?

Comment: to make it complete for other readers one could add the phrase just above  If F can be covered by $N_{\delta}(F )$ sets of diameter $\delta$, then, from definition (2.1), $H^s_{\delta}(F ) \le  N_{\delta}(F ) \delta^s$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result holds true as long as $\mathcal{H}^s(F) > 0$, though a slightly different argument is required.  The reason is that for $r>0$ we have 
$$\mathcal{H}^s(rF) = r^s\mathcal{H}(F),$$
where $rF=\{rx:x\in F\}$. Thus, for sufficiently large $r$ we have
$$\dim_H(rF)\leq\underline\dim_B(rF)\leq\overline\dim_B(rF).$$
Furthermore, $\dim(rF)=\dim(F)$ for all these definitions of dimension.

Comment: I wonder why you don't address the case $H^s(F) = 0$

Comment: @Rodrigo It is not required to address that case, since if $\dim_H F > 0$, one can always find $s \ge 0$ with $\mathcal H^s(F) > 0$. If for all $s \ge 0$, $\mathcal H^s(F) = 0$, then $\dim_H F = 0$ and the claim automatically follows.